# Developing an app for publishing various Facebook page tab apps to a user's page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to develop an  which allows users to publish various apps to their page as tab app. What is the correct API to be used so that user can select a page and publish with few parameter. No coding required. Wanted to know what is the specific API which allows this. We will be developing industry specific apps- hence can be used as a template.

I am not a techie- but want get a general knowledge for talking to developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding Page tab application to a Page Facebook utilizes **[Add Page Tab Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/)**. You can use the same using the JavaScript SDK or by creating the URL as documented in the link and open the link.